# Text is superimposed on top of another

Tags: c#, winforms

Good afternoon, for some reason my text is getting overwritten one on top of the other, this text is dynamic (in this print it is: "Private IP's:"), its length varies, and I wanted the text in front of it to have always a small spacing.

Code Style Label:

```
        this.labelIpss.AutoSize = true;
        this.labelIpss.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 111);
        this.labelIpss.Name = "labelIpss";
        this.labelIpss.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 13);
        this.labelIpss.TabIndex = 3;
        this.labelIpss.Text = "IP:";
```

Code style IP's List:

```
        this.ips.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top;
        this.ips.AutoSize = true;
        this.ips.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(42, 111);
        this.ips.Name = "ips";
        this.ips.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 13);
        this.ips.TabIndex = 6;
        this.ips.Text = "ips";
```

Code that adds ips to the list:

```
        Label privips = this.ips;
        Label labelips = this.labelIpss;
        string ips = "";
        string nome = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPAddress[] ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(nome);
        int tam = ip.Length;
        if(tam == 0)
        {
            labelIpss.Text = "IP Privado: ";
        }else{
            labelIpss.Text = "IP's Privados: ";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<tam; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                ips = ip[i].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                ips = ips + "\n" + ip[i].ToString();
            }
        }
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: `this.ips.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.labelIpss.Right + 4, 111);`  Otherwise, I'm not sure what's happening in your image.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But that's not the problem :(

Comment: Then what's the problem?  Are you changing the text of the labels?  Your code doesn't show that to us.

Comment: The problem is that the length of the field is probably not following the dynamic text, which means that the word "Privados" only appears a bit of the letter P, I just added that to the question.

Comment: Run my code after you change the labelIpss.Text, since the text "IP Privado:" is going to require more than 26 pixels, which is all you provided.

Comment: It worked, I had put your tag in style when putting it in the action code it worked

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)